# Best practices for ASP.NET web application localization

Tags: asp.net, localization, web-applications

I'm developing a web application that will need to be localized to English and Portuguese (and possible more languages later). I'm aware that the .NET Framework offers full support for UI localization, however, I'm not so sure what's the best approach to implement it.

What do you consider the best practices for a web application localization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also have a look at

[Globalization and Localization Demystified in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx)

Pretty good coverage and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Read *[ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)* and *[ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx)*, both from MSDN. I have found that following the Microsoft practices on localization is easy and does the job.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx not found