# How do I get the localized strings for Day, Week, Month, and Year in .Net

Tags: .net, localization

I know I can use `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName` and `GetDayName` to get the localized names of actual calendar parts like June, Friday, etc. Now I need the translated strings for the following words "**Day**", "**Week**", "**Month**", and "**Year**." Is it possible to get these from .net somehow?

Comment: Not possible, they are not there.

Comment: Agree with Hans. Your best bet would be something in the [System.Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abeh092z.aspx) namespace, but I don't see anything applicable in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the culture set, you can make use of date formatters to return the translated string. I'm not sure how you'd translate the year, however!

Here is a good reference for the formatters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

You can pass in a known date (instead of the current date) to get a specific day / month name.

**Given the update to your question, you're better off using resource files.**

Comment: I need the actual word "Year" translated not "2011". Format string will work for names of days or months not the words "Day" or "Month".

Comment: He apparently wants the *strings* »day«, »week«, »month« and »year«, not a local date format.

Comment: @Tim - you should edit your question and remove the word 'units.' This is not clear. Really, you want to use the framework to translate the words "day", "week", "month", "year." The resource file comment still stands.

Comment: I made the edit and upvoted your answer to balance out the -1 and because I think resource files are what I may have to use anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get that out of the .Net library.  But, you can get the information from a translation web service (if you really need it real-time).

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/

Or, if static is fine, just translate it ahead of time and store it in a resource:

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/
http://translate.google.com/

Answer (score -1):

This might be more up the right street:

[Best practices for ASP.NET web application localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455132/best-practices-for-asp-net-web-application-localization)

Comment: This answer is both generic and misses the point of the question - it is not useful.