# What is the best way for localization in webforms?

Tags: .net, asp.net, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices for ASP.NET web application localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455132/best-practices-for-asp-net-web-application-localization)

I want to ask for the best practice for localization in web forms.. I'm thinking in two ways but not satisfied with any of them:

1. use .resx to store languages and assign strings by : App_GlobalResources.Resources for each control.
2. to build my own controls and manipulate 'Render' method so that I can assign strings by assigning the keys to displaying properties (like 'Text' in labels).

Any better ideas ?

Thanx

**PS:**
I'm using .resx file in both methods

**UPDATE:**
And please, how can I know the proper .resx file to use depending on current choosen language of course.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel unless you want to learn the basics of a localization framework? Resource files sound like a good option.

Comment: @J.Steen It's good but I'm asking for the best way to get the strings from the .resx file and assign it to the controls

Comment: @Al0NE, I also do not understand why you need all this things if asp.net does all these things out-of-box...

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes an administrator of web site want to have an access to change any text in any language table, so in this case you have to stick with an approach, when localization are stored in a data base. 
For other cases I would agree with guys which are suggesting to do not reinvent a wheel and use standard approach for
"[Localizing ASP.NET Web Pages By Using Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208.aspx)"